# Pass vb.net session variable to jquery

Tags: jquery, vb.net

I am trying to pass a session variable to jquery. Basically what I'm wanting is when I click my 'btnVenSUSend' button, I want an alert box to pop up and let the user know that their info has been submitted. I'm filling the session variable when it passes through the code to write information to the database. I had a problem with the alert box popping up even if the form wasn't complete. I only want the alert if my session variable = send.

Here is my JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ($) {
        $("#btnVenSUSend").click(function ($) {
            var mySend = '<%=Session("mySend") %>'
            if (mySend == "send") {
                alert("Your request has been submitted, you will be notified when the process is complete.");
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Here is my code behind. If the condition of VenType is correct, it passes through and sets the variable. This works because I can step through the code and see the results.

```
If VenType = "E" Then
        str = "send"
        Session("mySend") = str

        Dim con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("VendorPortalConnectionString").ToString())
        Dim cmdO As New SqlCommand("Select UserID, Password FROM VendorMaster where UserID = '" & loggedIn & "'", con)
        con.Open()

        Dim myReader As SqlDataReader
        myReader = cmdO.ExecuteReader()

        Dim UserID As String = ""
        Dim psw As String = ""

        If myReader.HasRows Then
            Do While myReader.Read
                UserID = myReader.GetString(0)
                psw = myReader.GetString(1)
            Loop
        Else
        End If
        con.Close()
        myReader.Close()
```

It's just my jquery that isn't working. My jquery is not in an external js. It is in the head of my .aspx page.

Comment: Where in your code behind are you setting the session variable?  Without seeing where it is being executed, I'd have to assume that you are always setting session("mySend") to "send", and therefore, your JavaScript alert would always be executed.

Comment: have you verified that the "`var mySend`" actually gets printed? If this is in an external js file it won't render the .net tag

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are missing a semi-colon in the mySend var declaration in your jQuery code. Does it work when you add it in (see below)?

```
var mySend = '<%=Session("mySend") %>';
```